# Can not install any software because of package error

Tags: apt-get, linux-mint

I am trying to install k3b through the terminal with `sudo apt-get install k3b` but when I do that it gives me the following error: `The package slack-desktop needs to be reinstalled, but cant find an archive for it`.

I don't care about this slack-desktop package, so I thought removing it with `sudo apt-get remove slack-desktop` would resolve the problem, which unfortunatly did not resolve the problem. So I tried the `purge` command, but no luck with that neither. How can I resolve this problem so I can install new software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all slack-desktop
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
```

Also you can remove it as follow:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.backup
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> then type `slack-desktop` , Only remove/comment out the `slack-desktop` entry.

Save and exit.

Update and install `k3b`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install k3b
```